# Cookies in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

For some reason I'm completely unable to get cookies to append in Core 3.1. I'm in a project that was recently upgraded from 2.2 to 3.1 so that might be relevant.

The code for adding cookies:

```
            var options = new CookieOptions
            {
                IsEssential = true,
                Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(60)
            };
            this.pageModel.Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, options);
```

(trying to add options here to get around some GDPR issues in 3.1 from what I found searching online)

I'm (trying to) retrieve it like this (although I'm fairly sure the issue isn't retrieving the cookie, but setting it, due to debugging):

`this.pageModel.Request.Cookies[key];`

In my Startup file I'm running `app.UseCookiePolicy();` under Configure and

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```

Under ConfigureServices.

I've been unable to find any further lead as to what I could possibly be doing wrong.

Comment: You old cookies may not work.  For example the old authentication may be using TLS 1.1 and now the server is using TLS 1.2.  You also may need to use a new certificate if the encryption mode has changed.  When was the last time you tried old code?  Does it still work?

Comment: @jdweng nothing has changed besides the .net core version as far as I'm aware. It also happens when i test locally. The upgrade is very recent, it's not even in production yet.

Comment: You said you are upgrading from Core 2.2 to Core 3.1 so the cookies could be from the 2.2 and you are using with 3.1.  When you are doing development as you make changes you have to delete cookies when you make changes.  The cookies are remembering settings from older code.

Comment: Obviously I've deleted all browser data and tested different browsers etc.

Comment: Did you delete cookies?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I deleted all browser data. That includes cookies.